# QML : How to align image with other image

Tags: qt, qml

How can I align my image `2.png` so that it aligns to left of image `1.png`?

At present image `1.png` has some invisible area at the bottom, because of which my image `2.png` does not start aligned to image `1.png`.

I am using QT-4.10.0 version.

How can I move image `2.png` so that it aligns to left of image `1.png`?

This worked `anchors.bottomMargin: 45`

```
Window
{
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480


    Rectangle
    {
        id: cluster
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Image
        {
            id: cluster_dial
            source: "files/test/1.png"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Image
        {
            id: cluster_teltail_left
            source: "files/test/2.png"
            anchors.right: cluster_dial.left
            anchors.bottom: cluster_dial.bottom
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? I copied your example and using twice the same images seems to work as expected.

Comment: I am using QT-4.10.0 version. how can i move 2.png little up from the bottom of window to align it to 1.png image.

Comment: You can try to use `anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter` on that Image instead of anchoring the bottom

Comment: this worked anchors.bottomMargin: 45